# Modify widget content

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget

I am using the script: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?script=bbr_standings&amp;params=bbr_standings_conf:E,bbr_standings_css:1&amp"></script>` which will display the NBA standing. Everything is working fine but on the top of the table, heading **Table** is coming which I don't want. Can we modify this? If yes then how to remove this?? [Sample: the heading table highlighted with yellow color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlYXD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Well opening up the href link pulls up the JS code. You can technically just copy the code, make a separate js file and just link it via your directory instead of linking it via a http:site.

look for `<table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table" id="" data-cols-to-freeze=0><caption> Table </caption>`

You can edit that in between text and change it. Cheers!